# How to show grid view in hover of any container in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How can we show related data in grid view from database on hover when we mouse move on that contain?

Comment: What kind of data you want to show on mouse over, is there any text you want to display ?

Comment: no i want data from database like grid view .. i want same like telerik tooltip control

Comment: thanks you change title but do you have solutions of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MasterDetail.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/NestableGridView.aspx

Comment: no i don't want like this.. i want like telerik tooltip control